# How to connect reactJS front-end with PHP?

Tags: php, reactjs, yii

I am developing a front-end with ReactJS.

How can I serve this app via PHP (plain PHP or Yii1)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by connect? Is your app already server by some server and you want to call a PHP or Yii1 API, or do you want to serve your  app with PHP or Yii1?

Comment: oh sorry about my question. Actually @NinoFiliu I nedd to integrate my reactApp with PHP or Yii. I wanted to get to know about, how my app serve with PHP.

Comment: Ok - I edited your question accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you'd want to go through the HTTP Protocol to create communication between the two.

In ReactJSX you want to make a fetch/get call that is provided with an EndPoint/REST from your backend.

```
// at the beginning of your file
import axios from 'axios';

// in your component constructor
state = {
  yourStateWithTheRecievedData: "",
}

// as a component method
componentDidMount = () => {
  axios
    .get('http://localhost:8080/YourBackendAPI')
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({
        yourStateWithTheRecievedData: response.data.yourStateWithTheRecievedData
      })
      console.log(response.data.yourStateWithTheRecievedData)
    })
}
```

You should now have a state with the data you've recieved. If you have a hard time doing this, i suggest you start off by first applying it to a public API.
You can find a list of public API's  [here](https://github.com/toddmotto/public-apis)

Comment: It was indeed hard to understand what the OP tried to do, nevertheless this doesn't answer the question, which has now been edited for clarity